# Monitor ASP.NET code behind

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Let's say I have a simple code-behind file:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass instance = new MyClass();
        instance.MyMethod();
    }

    protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnUnload(e);
        var trace = Environment.StackTrace;
        Debug.WriteLine(trace);
    }
}
```

Here's the output (I've shortened it a bit):

```
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at WebTesting.Default.OnUnload(EventArgs e) in d:\Projects\07\WebTesting\WebTesting\Default.aspx.cs:line 28
   at System.Web.UI.Control.UnloadRecursive(Boolean dispose)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.UnloadRecursive(Boolean dispose)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestCleanup()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\8bc80b93\42174b23\App_Web_ut1iqnjz.0.cs:line 0
```

As you can see the output does not contain any call to Myclass.MyMethod(). The question is: how can I trace the method? What I need is a trace of every method call that happened during the page execution. Is it possible?